# jquery hover with if/else statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement, hover

I have a hover state that I want to use, but only if the opacity is not .65, this is what I have but it's not quite working, not sure exactly how to change it.  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
$('.info_btn').hover(
  var jthis = this;
  if($('.info_btn').css('opacity') == 0.65) { }
  else {
    function() {
        $(jthis).css({
              "opacity": "0.7",
              "-moz-opacity": "0.7",
              "filter": "alpha(opacity = 70)"
        });
    }, function() {
        $(jthis).css({
              "opacity": "0.2",
              "-moz-opacity": "0.2",
              "filter": "alpha(opacity = 20)"
        });
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: "Not working" is _never_ a sufficient problem description.

Comment: [Bind one or two handlers to the matched elements, to be executed when the mouse pointer enters and leaves the elements.](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) You've invalid syntax. `jQuery hover` expects 1 or 2 functions as arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one only binds the events to the only `.info_btn` elements that have `opaticy == 0.65`. Useful in case you've lots of `.info_btn` elements

```
        $('.info_btn').filter(function () {
           return parseFloat($(this).css('opacity')) == 0.65
        }).on({
              mouseover: function () {
                 $(this).css({
                    "opacity": "0.7",
                    "-moz-opacity": "0.7",
                    "filter": "alpha(opacity = 70)"
                 });
              },
              mouseout: function () {
                 $(this).css({
                    "opacity": "0.2",
                    "-moz-opacity": "0.2",
                    "filter": "alpha(opacity = 20)"
                 });
              }
           });
```

It let's you maintain the condition `opacity == 0.65` in one place, doesn't attach events to extra `.info_btn` elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.info_btn').mouseover(function() {
     if($(this).css('opacity') == 0.65) { }
});
```

This is all you need for what you described in your question.

mouseover and hover are kinda the same thing
http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/
http://api.jquery.com/hover/